# Is there something equivalent to solr's UpdateRequestProcessor in Elasticsearch?

Tags: solr, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I want to create a plugin that adds a new field to the document before it get indexed. In Solr there is a specific component for this purpose [UpdateRequestProcessor](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor).

Is there something similar for elasticsearch?

Comment: At least in 2010 there was no such option, because ES would pull-parse documents directly to into a lucene index: http://elasticsearch-users.115913.n3.nabble.com/Document-pre-processor-td979569.html

Comment: Thanks for the link. It makes sense. What a shame, because I see it quite useful. Process documents before index and consume from different clients in different languages.

Comment: A lot has changed since 2010, maybe there's a way today. But honestly, I find it convincing to do field mangling on the client side and let ES focus on the search part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although some rivers support scripting to modify documents that are going to be indexed, that would definitely slow indexing down and is not supported within elasticsearch itself.

Doing this work in the client side is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

I just built a [tool](https://github.com/jmlucjav/esURP) that allows you to use Solr's UpdateRequestProcessor in Elasticsearch.